# Destroy all farms or not?

Tags: tropico-4

I'm playing Tropico 4: Modern Times.
I was wondering if it's okay to destroy all farms at once when you are asked to when bio farms are available.
Or do you need a special strategy to do it (like destroying half of the food farms and replacing them, then destroying the other half, after the bio farm is really producing)?